# Software & Updates permission failed

Tags: software-installation, software-center, update-manager, authentication, policykit

```
OS: Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS x86_64
Kernel: 4.15.0-135-generic
DE: MATE
```

When i run Software & Updates i get the following error:

> You are not allowed to perform this action
> You don't have the required privileges to perform this action.
> org.freedesktop.PolicyKit.Error.Failed: ('system-bus-name', {'name':
> ':1.83'}): org.debian.apt.update-cache

When i run `sudo /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/polkit-mate/polkit-mate-authentication-agent-1` i get

> (polkit-mate-authentication-agent-1:3261): polkit-mate-1-WARNING **: 02:37:25.097: Unable to determine the session we are in: No session for pid 3261

When my desktop starts, i dont have a login screen. Not sure if it has anything to do with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated to 20.04 now the error is gone